# How to get the current field name in Tridion?

Tags: tridion

I adding a button to the ribbon tool bar in Tridion 2011 SP1. When I click on the button it will open an aspx page.Inside that aspx page I need to access the current field name where the cursor is presently. Please provide me which object to be used? For schema name I used `$display.getView().getItem().getSchemaId()`. Similarly is there any way to get the current field name?

Comment: Can you give some more details? Are we to assume this the ribbon bar of the Component View? The ribbon bar has lots of locations, so understanding the context is important to answer the  question. Can you modify your question accordingly? It may be worth including a fragment of your editor.config so that we can see where your button is applied.

Comment: @ChrisSummers Thank you for your response. Yes, I am adding my button to the ribbon bar of component view.

Comment: @ChrisSummers Can you please tell me how to get the parent field name in case of subfield. Structure is shown below: Body: name: value: In the above case Value field is a RTF. From value field if I click on the ribbon tool bar button how to get the parent field name(That is "body")? Please help me in this issue.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest I got is using this code (in the Component edit window):

```
$display.getView().getSourceEditorName()
```

This will return the **name of the current field**, even though the method name suggests it does something else.

If you want to get the same value from your popup, call it on the `opener` like this:

```
opener.$display.getView().getSourceEditorName()
```

### Better solution

Instead of looking up the field name from within the popup, you should really pass it into your popup as a argument when your command is invoked. You can get it from the `target` parameter that is passed to the `_execute` method of your Command.

```
GUI.Extension.prototype._execute = function GUI$Extension$_execute(target) {
    target.editor.setFocus();
    var fieldName = target.item.getSourceEditorName();
    var popup = $popup.create("/WebUI/Editors/GUI.Extensions/Extension.aspx",
                "width=400px,height=150px,resizable=0",
                { fieldName: fieldName });
}
```

And then read it in your popup's JavaScript using:

```
var fieldName = window.dialogArguments.fieldName;
```

Comment: the above answer will help to findthe current field name. Can you please tell me how to get the parent field name in case of subfield. Structure is shown below:

Body:
  name:
  value:


In the above case Value field is a RTF. From value field if I click on the ribbon tool bar button how to get the parent field name(That is "body")?
   Please help me in this issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to get the parent field name? Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you already try? I've done a lot of groundwork for you to get to the answer above. You can't keep depending on others to do the deep delving into Tridion's GUI code for you. Search for how fields relate, document your findings and THEN ask a follow up question.

Comment: @Puff Thanks for the above solution. I am able to send the value to the popup script. But I want to use that value in code behind page, How can I use it?Thanks in advance.

Comment: In that case you can simply pass it to the server as part of the URL when opening the popup: $popup.create("/WebUI/Editors/GUI.Extensions/Extension.aspx?fieldName="+fieldName...

Comment: @Puff I have a small doubt please clarify it. In the pop up page which is opening from the Ribbon tool bar button will work if we go for Auto Post Back or Multiple server requests? If you are not understanding the context exactly I will post a separate question.Thanks in advance.

Comment: dialogArguments will not be preserved when the window is reloaded. Whether the parameters you specify in a URL are preserved when ASP.NET does a postback, sounds more like a question for ASP.NET experts.